# Right-aligning text with different font sizes

Tags: alignment

The desired result should be as follows

[image]

What I've tried so far is `\raggedleft` and `tabular` with `r`. But the results are not as desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont

{\raggedleft\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont Journal\par}
{\raggedleft\fontsize{32}{32}\selectfont 2021\par}
{\raggedleft\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont Vol. 1\par}
{\raggedleft\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont Issue 1\par}

\begin{tabular}{r}
{\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont Journal}\\
{\fontsize{32}{32}\selectfont 2021}\\
{\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont Vol. 1}\\
{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont Issue 1}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This is what I get

[image]

Comment: And with `{r@{}}` as the tabular preamble?

Comment: you are using lining digits 0-9 all have the same width so that columns of numbers look right, this means that 1 has a lot of white space within the actual character box about which TeX has no information. So you could switch to a font with proportional digits or add a small negative space to adjust by eye.

Comment: @Bernard `{r@{}}` has no effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The digits you are using are designed so that tabular columns of numbers line up, so they all have the same width. To achieve this 1 has a lot of white space within the character box. Tex has no control over that. You could choose a font with proportional digits where each digit has its "natural" width, or as here simply adjust by eye.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont

{\raggedleft\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont Journal\par}
{\raggedleft\fontsize{32}{32}\selectfont 2021\kern-.13em\par}
{\raggedleft\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont Vol. 1\kern-.1em\par}
{\raggedleft\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont Issue 1\kern-.01em\par}

\begin{tabular}{r@{\vline}}
{\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont Journal}\\
{\fontsize{32}{32}\selectfont 2021\kern-.13em}\\
{\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont Vol. 1\kern-.1em}\\
  {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont Issue 1\kern-.01em}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!